# String and Map Comparison

Tags: java, collections

How do I compare each letter in a String with keys of a Map?
If each letter exists as a key of the map, change it the capital letter.

```
String str = "abcdef";
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("a", "A");
map.put("b", "B");
map.put("c", "C");
map.put("d", "D");
map.put("e", "E");
```

The result should be `"ABCDEf"`.
If the letter in the String does not exist in the Map, that letter will be left in place.

Comment: By "alphabet" do you mean "letter"?

Comment: Yes, I want to change "a" to "A" and the result should be ABCDEf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
String after = Stream.of(str.split(""))  // a stream of a String for each letter
                     .map(c-> map.getOrDefault(c, c)) // look up replacement or leave
                     .collect(Collectors.joining("")); //join into string with no separator
```

> How do I use String#toCharArray() and String.ValueOf(char[] data)

You can use a loop instead with.

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length;i ++)
    chars[i] = map.getOrDefault(""+chars[i], ""+chars[i]).charAt(0);
String after = new String(chars);
```

Comment: How do I use String#toCharArray() and String.ValueOf(char[] data) method without using emptyString (str.split("")) ?

Comment: @H_M You can do something like this but it's not pretty. It would help if you used a `Map<Character, Character> map` instead.